# AngularJS routing in VF page giving error

Tags: apex, visualforce, angularjs

I am trying to use **AngularJs routing in Visualforce page**. I have my file structure as mentioned below:
-AngularApp (static resource)
-app
---controllers
---directives
---services
---views
--app.js

I want to direct user on a button click, all .html files are in views folder

In app.js, i have written:

```
var app = angular.module('workOrderApp',['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) 
{       


$routeProvider


             // route for the home page by default
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'views/createWorkOrder.html',
                controller  : 'woFormController'
            })             
            // route for the work order grid page.
            .when('/getWorkOrder', {
                templateUrl : 'views/workOrderGrid.html',
                controller  : 'searchWOController'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });

}]);
```

In VF page i have written:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularJSLib, 'angular.min.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularJSLib, 'angular-route.min.js')}"/>
<base href="{!URLFOR($Resource.AngularApp, 'app/')}" /> 



<div ng-app="workOrderApp"  class="container" width="100%">        
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
```

After redirection i am able to view the page, but it is give an alert saying:
Invalid criteria specified for retrieval.

> ValidationError [code=11, message=Data does not match any schemas from
>   "oneOf", path=/where, schemaKey=null]

How can i resolve this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it by redirecting it from a button, actually i was trying to enter the url manually giving a '/#' tag in url.I guess thats may be the issue.